# вызвать функцию кнопкой на клавиатуре

Tags: javascript

```
<a style="float: right;" id="refresh"><i data-toggle="tooltip" id="reload" class="icon-f fa fa-retweet" style="cursor:pointer" title="Оновити"></i></a>
<script>
playlistRefresh('<?=$id?>');
</script>
```

Работает!
Хочу, чтобы при нажатии CTRL, запускалась функция playlistRefresh();

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 17) {
    playlistRefresh('<?=$id?>');
  }
}
)
```

не работает :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 17) {
    console.log('test');
  }
});
$("input").focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Press Ctrl</h2>
<input />
```